# Display Plugin Panels Outside of Admin Areas

Tags: plugins, wp-admin, hooks, admin-menu

I'm trying to find a way to display the work area content of different plugins on pages/posts/areas aside from the admin backend.

For example, how would I display the options panel for a certain plugin in a page instead of it's default location? If the plugin also has an output view, like Google Analytics dashboard, how would I call that output content to display in a post?

I essentially want to move a lot of the settings and other panels from the admin areas to other locations, or have them display in other locations where they're called.

Any pointers on how I might go about that?

Answer (score 2):

Look at the markup for the callback function called by `add_theme_page()` or `add_settings_page()`, and use that markup to create a custom Page template.

For code that simply outputs content, this should be fairly straight-forward; for code that actually saves settings, you're probably going to have to do more work in order to create front-end data submission. In such case, you might want to look at something like the P2 Theme, to see how it handles front-end post submissions.

However, before attempting something like this, be sure that you fully understand the security implications of taking such code/content out of the Admin area and putting it into the publicly accessible front-end.